# Clean array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

My implementation is such that i have :

```
var test = [{},{},{}];
```

My test var is an array of objects. In this the last object can be empty or have keys.

I need to remove this last object always if it is empty.

What i have written right now works and its thus :

```
var lengthofTest = test.length;
if(Object.keys(test[lengthofTest]).length == 0) {
 test.pop();
 }
```

Is there a better way of doing it? Anything more direct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way of doing it?

Depends on your definition of "better." :-) For me, that's a good way except for a couple of details:

1. You'll want `test[lengthofTest - 1]`, not `test[lengthofTest]`. (Remember, indexes start at `0`, so it's `0` through `length - 1`.)
2. You don't need the variable
3. There's no need for `pop` if you're not using the result, just decrement `length`

So:

```
if (Object.keys(test[test.length - 1]).length == 0) {
  --test.length;
}
```

> Anything more direct?

You could use `for-in`:

```
var lengthofTest = test.length;
for (var key in test[lengthofTest-1]) {
    if (test[lengthofTest-1].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        --test.length;
        break;
    }
}
```

...but as you can see it's a lot more verbose, and in the above it's assuming no non-index properties on the array (details about what I mean by that [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)).

Comment: yup!!! Just ran it to realise i missed the lengthOfTest-1. And yes the second method is very verbose. :) Thank you!

Comment: @BhumiSinghal: I added a couple of minor notes above. Regards,

Comment: that is nyc .. i like point 3. Though I have to keep the var since my actual object is deep in object heirarchy .. so just would be better to have a var for the length